# Mvc Caching disable object changes tracking

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, change-tracking

i'm using caching in my mvc 5 website,
i have an object available in the cache.
when i get this object lets call it object1 from the cache and copy it to another object lets call it object2.
every changes i perform it on object2 this changes automatically reflected to object1 and to the cached object
now when i get the object again from the cache it will modefied with the changes i have made to objec2 because of changes tracking and i don't need that
how can i avoid refelect the changes to cache

here is my code

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //a model with 10 adds
        Model model = new Model()
        {
            pageName = "test",
            ads = new List<Ads>()
            {
                new Ads() {id = 1, image = "1" },
                new Ads() {id = 2, image = "2" },
                new Ads() {id = 3, image = "3" },
                new Ads() {id = 4, image = "4" },
                new Ads() {id = 5, image = "5" },
                new Ads() {id = 6, image = "6" },
                new Ads() {id = 7, image = "7" },
                new Ads() {id = 8, image = "8" },
                new Ads() {id = 9, image = "9" },
                new Ads() {id = 10, image = "10" },
            },
        };

        //cache it
        HttpContext.Cache.Insert("demo", model, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

        //get cached object
        Model object1 = HttpContext.Cache.Get("demo") as Model;

        // => 10 items
        Console.WriteLine(model.ads.Count());

        //just get 3 items of that list
        Model object2 = object1; // disable changes tracking here
        object2.ads = object2.ads.Take(3).ToList();
        //this changes will be reflected to cached object, i need to disable this


        //get cached object (from cache) again
        Model newCachedModel = HttpContext.Cache.Get("demo") as Model;
        Console.WriteLine(newCachedModel.ads.Count());//3 items only
        //note i have never change the cached object, the changes reflected from modelToReturn (using changes tracking feature in c#)

        return View(object2);
    }
}
public class Model
{
    public string pageName { get; set; }
    public List<Ads> ads { get; set; }
}
public class Ads
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find a solution
just make a clone of the object before do any changes to it

```
    public class Model
    {
        public string pageName { get; set; }
        public List<Ads> ads { get; set; }

        public Model clone()
        {
            return (Model)this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }

    //after clone any changes to object2 will not reflect to object1
    Model object2 = object1.clone();
```